# Excel scatter graph line only "connects data points with line" even with #N/A in source cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Excel scatter graph line only "connects data points with line" even with #N/A in the source cells. I have tried using different scatter graph line types but all interpolate the data over the ranges where #N/A is returned in the source cell using the N/A() function. I have "show empty cells shown as gaps" selected.

Any bright ideas!?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula can return NA() or "", but neither is interpreted as a blank cell: one's an error value, and the other is a short text string. The marker for NA() is omitted, and the line connects points on either side of the NA(). A marker for "" is placed at zero, since Excel interprets text as zero.

You have to manually or programmatically delete the contents of a cell in order for the chart to consider it a blank cell. Or you could manually or programmatically format the connecting line that spans the non-blank cell to use "no line".

Not the bright idea you wanted, but these are the best I've ever come across.

EDIT: A recent (late 2017) enhancement to Excel 2016 treats #N/A like a blank cell. (If you have Office 365, you can toggle this setting.) Finally now we can have a formula produce a result which is plotted as a gap.